# Push new branch to google.com git repository

Tags: git

Starting from an existing code.google project, and having successfully pushed initial code.

I created a new branch on the local copy.  I committed the changes for the branch and now I want to push the branch to code.google repo.  I type this:

```
git push origin branch_name -v https://username:password@code.google.com/p/project-name/
```

But I get this error

> fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://username:password@code.google.com/p/project-name/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `push` command:

```
git push [ <options> ] <repository> [ <refspec> ]
```

In the simplest case, `<options>` is empty, `<repository>` is typically `origin`, and `<refspec>` is the name of your current branch:

```
git push origin branch_name
```

This assumes that you have created a remote named `origin`, either by cloning a remote repository or using the `git remote add ...` command.  If you haven't configured a remote, you can substitute the URL on the command line like this:

```
git push https://username:password@code.google.com/p/project-name/ branch_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally you don't need to specify the full URL of a push destination, because the remote `origin` already points to that (type `git remote -v` for a list). So perhaps all you need is:

```
git push origin branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Pushing local branch as new on remote server:

> git push origin local_branch_name:remote_branch_name_that_will_be_created